# Landscape table

Tags: tables, errors, captions, landscape

I'm trying to create a landscape table, but I get an error message saying the caption is outside the float. I don't know how to fix it.

Here is the code.

```
\usepackage{lscape}
\begin{landscape}
    \small
    \begin{center}
    \caption{Central composite design in the original and coded (between brackets) form of the independent variables percentage of modifier (A), temperature  (B) and pressure (C) and experimental results for the response variables, retention factors of lycopene (k$_{1}$), beta-carotene (k$_{2}$), coenzyme Q10 (k$_{3}$) and lutein (k$_{4}$) and separation factors of the pairs lycopene/beta-carotene ($\alpha_{12}$), beta-carotene/coenzyme Q10 ($\alpha_{23}$) and coenzyme Q10/lutein ($\alpha_{34}$), between brackets the standard deviation.}
    \label{ANOVA4a}
    \begin{tabular}{P{1.0cm}|P{3cm}|P{2.9cm}|P{2.3cm}|P{1.5cm}|P{1.5cm}|P{1.5cm}|P{1.5cm}|P{1.5cm}|P{1.5cm}|P{1.5cm}}
    \hline
    \textbf{Run} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Factor}} & \multicolumn{7}{c}{\textbf{Response}}\\
    \hline
     & Percentage of modifier (A) & Temperature (B) & Pressure (C) & k$_{1}$ & k$_{2}$ & k$_{3}$ & k$_{4}$ & $\alpha_{12}$ & $\alpha_{23}$ & $\alpha_{34}$\\
    \hline
     1 & 24 (+1) & 25 (-1) & 2200 (+1) & 1.59 ($\pm$0.02) & 2.01 ($\pm$0.02) & 2.01 ($\pm$0.02) & 3.63 ($\pm$0.02) &    1.27 ($<$0.01) & 0.97 ($\pm$0.04) & 1.80 ($<$0.01)\\
     \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{landscape}
```

Comment: Please tell us how the `P` column type is defined.

Comment: It was defined as \newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}. Thank you. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

`landscape` is the environment which helps to rotate the page, you need to give `\begin{table}...\end{table}`, refer the modified tags:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lscape}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
    \small
    \begin{center}
    \caption{Central composite design in the original and coded (between brackets) form of the independent variables percentage of modifier (A), temperature  (B) and pressure (C) and experimental results for the response variables, retention factors of lycopene (k$_{1}$), beta-carotene (k$_{2}$), coenzyme Q10 (k$_{3}$) and lutein (k$_{4}$) and separation factors of the pairs lycopene/beta-carotene ($\alpha_{12}$), beta-carotene/coenzyme Q10 ($\alpha_{23}$) and coenzyme Q10/lutein ($\alpha_{34}$), between brackets the standard deviation.}
    \label{ANOVA4a}
    \begin{tabular}{p{1.0cm}|p{3cm}|p{2.9cm}|p{2.3cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}}
    \hline
    \textbf{Run} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Factor}} & \multicolumn{7}{c}{\textbf{Response}}\\
    \hline
     & Percentage of modifier (A) & Temperature (B) & Pressure (C) & k$_{1}$ & k$_{2}$ & k$_{3}$ & k$_{4}$ & $\alpha_{12}$ & $\alpha_{23}$ & $\alpha_{34}$\\
    \hline
     1 & 24 (+1) & 25 (-1) & 2200 (+1) & 1.59 ($\pm$0.02) & 2.01 ($\pm$0.02) & 2.01 ($\pm$0.02) & 3.63 ($\pm$0.02) &    1.27 ($<$0.01) & 0.97 ($\pm$0.04) & 1.80 ($<$0.01)\\
     \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Better to use the `rotating` package instead of `lscape` and the tag is

```
\begin{sidewaystable}...\end{sidewaystable}
```

PS: I've changed your `tabular` alignment from `P{1.0cm}` to `p{1.0cm}`...

Comment: Thank you for correcting the code. P was defined as you mentioned

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that the `P` column type is a centered version of the basic `p` column type.

My main suggestion is to load the `rotating` package and use its `sidewaystable` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article} % or "11pt", "12pt", etc.
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage{rotating} % for "sidewaystable" environment
\usepackage{array} % for "\newcolumntype" and "\extrarowheight" macros
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}} % ??

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
    %\centering
    %\small
    \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a more open "look"

    \caption{Central composite design in the original and coded (between brackets) form 
    of the independent variables percentage of modifier~(A), temperature~(B) and 
    pressure~(C) and experimental results for the response variables, retention 
    factors of lycopene~($k_{1}$), beta-carotene~($k_{2}$), coenzyme Q10~($k_{3}$) 
    and lutein~($k_{4}$) and separation factors of the pairs lycopene\slash 
    beta-carotene~($\alpha_{12}$), beta-carotene\slash coenzyme Q10~($\alpha_{23}$) 
    and coenzyme Q10\slash lutein~($\alpha_{34}$), between brackets the 
    standard deviation.}
    \label{ANOVA4a}

    \medskip
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|P{2.7cm}|P{2.5cm}|P{1.7cm}|*{7}{P{1.5cm}|}}
    \hline
    \textbf{Run} &
    \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{Factor}} &
    \multicolumn{7}{c|}{\textbf{Response}}\\
    \hline
     & Percentage of modifier (A)
     & Temperature (B)
     & Pressure (C)
     & $k_{1}$ & $k_{2}$ & $k_{3}$ & $k_{4}$
     & $\alpha_{12}$ & $\alpha_{23}$ & $\alpha_{34}$\\
    \hline
     1 & 24 ($+1$) & 25 ($-1$) & 2200 ($+1$)
     & 1.59 ($\pm0.02$) & 2.01 ($\pm0.02$) & 2.01 ($\pm0.02$)
     & 3.63 ($\pm0.02$) & 1.27 ($<0.01$)   & 0.97 ($\pm0.04$)
     & 1.80 ($<0.01$)\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```